# Orient DB - create orient db with password and check if one available using JAVA

Tags: java, remote-access, orientdb

I saw that we can create orient db using:

```
ODatabaseDocumentTx db2 = new ODatabaseDocumentTx ( "local:C:/temp/db/scratchpad" ).create();
```

But how can we create orientDB database using password with REMOTE type. And does that checks if a database exists and say. Or if found will it overwrite?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for this:

```
void createDB(){
    new OServerAdmin("remote:localhost")
            .connect("root", "rootPassword")
            .createDatabase("databaseName", "graph", "plocal").close();
}
```

See [here](http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/Document-Database.html#on-a-remote-server).

---

**UPDATE:**

In the above, if the database already exists, an exception will be thrown.
Maybe you'll find these methods more useful:

```
private static final String dbUrl = "remote:localhost/databaseName";
private static final String dbUser = "root";
private static final String dbPassword = "rootPassword";

public static void createDBIfDoesNotExist() throws IOException {

    OServerAdmin server = new OServerAdmin(dbUrl).connect(dbUser, dbPassword);
    if (!server.existsDatabase("plocal")) {
        server.createDatabase("graph", "plocal");
    }
    server.close();
}

public static void dropDBIfExists() throws IOException {

    OServerAdmin server = new OServerAdmin(dbUrl).connect(dbUser, dbPassword);
    if (server.existsDatabase("plocal")) {
        server.dropDatabase("plocal");
    }
    server.close();
}
```

Comment: Small Note: the default user/password will be "admin/admin". Can find this under "config/orientdb-server-config.xm".